# How to send message to dead letter queue in Azure service bus function using QueueClient?

Tags: .net, azureservicebus, .net-7.0, azure-servicebus-queues, dead-letter

Using the latest .net framework: .net 7.0 I need to figure out how to dead letter a message if my azure function throws an exception.

### MessageReceiver and ServiceBusMessageActions

I tried the following solutions:

[How to manually send message to service bus dead letter queue in Azure Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58017552/how-to-manually-send-message-to-service-bus-dead-letter-queue-in-azure-function)

[How to redirect message to dead-letter queue Azure Service Bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76780091/how-to-redirect-message-to-dead-letter-queue-azure-service-bus)

But the only input type my function supports is string. In both cases, my function would throw an error indicating it can't convert MessageReceiver to string or ServiceBusReceivedMessage to string.

### QueueClient

Using IQueueClient to dead letter a message seems to be the microsoft recommended solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.deadletterasync?view=azure-dotnet

However I run into 2 issues:

1. I don't know how to reference the azure service bus connection string from local.settings.json when newing up a QueueClient.
2. If I hard code the connection string and queue name to get around the first issue, I have to generate a new Guid for the lock token. I then get this error:
   `The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue, or was received by a different receiver instance.` I'm not sure if I'm supposed to generate a new Guid for the token or where to get it? It wants a 32 digit GUID even though the token parameter is of type string not GUID. It will throw an error indicating it's not a GUID if I put a random string in there like "MyLockToken".

Here's my code:

```
    [Function("MyFunction")]        
    [ServiceBusOutput("%OutputQueueName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]
    public async Task<string> Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%InputQueueName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] string queueItem, string messageId) // , MessageReceiver messageReceiver
    {         
        try
        {
            // process message
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            IQueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient("ServiceBusConnectionString", "%InputQueueName%"); // error here, can't find settings in local.settings.json
            await queueClient.DeadLetterAsync("MyLockToken", "ProcessingError", ex.Message); // or Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        }       
        
        return "message processed";
    }
```

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific about using the QueueClient. The referenced duplicate question is not a duplicate because it's talking about using ServiceBusMessageActions and not QueueClient.